# cloud-init didn't work with my self-built kernel image

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, cloud, qemu, cloud-init

When I use qemu to boot my VM with official kernel image and initrd dowmloaded from ubuntu official webset, it works well, but when I build the kernel from source, and replace the kernel image with my own built one (the initrd was still the official one), the OS can still boot, but cloud-init can't set the user's password correctly. so I can't login to my OS anymore.

Comment: How did you generate a correct config?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with cloud-init obviously, but to get started debugging you might compare `/var/log/cloud-init.log` between the working and non-working kernels.

If you are running cloud-init multiple times on the same system, don't forget that a `cloud-init clean --logs` is required to get cloud-init to rerun fully since cloud-init doesn't run all module every boot.